# How do I migrate a question to a site that is not on the list?

Tags: support, migration

I want to migrate [Term rewriting; Compute critical pairs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419967/term-rewriting-compute-critical-pairs) to [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) as suggested in one of the comments to the question.

How can I do this given the fact that the site is not on the list?[image: List]

Comment: You do what you did, flag for moderator attention requesting a migration. And then wait until one of us finds the time to look whether a migration is appropriate.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Ok, thanks! I thought it was wrong after I red a post describing I should flag it as Off-Topic > Migration, and after waiting for 8 hours. (no rudeness intended).

Comment: If the desired target site is not in the default list, only moderators can migrate it, so the post needs moderator attention. If it is in the list, also ordinary users can migrate, then the `Off-Topic > Migration` flag is right. [If the question gets closed without being migrated, it may still need a moderator attention flag.] And sure, 8 hours looks like a lot of time when you wait for something. But not when it's only one of many things that need attention.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to leave a Comment explaining why the Question is considered Off-Topic.  If it is on-topic at Math.SE but may also be on-topic at another specific site, I often leave a Comment suggesting the OP do a search for related questions at the alternate site, while waiting a decent interval to see if useful responses appear here.

Comment: Note that the OP here (meta) is also the poster of the Question he wishes to migrate.